# Why are the rewards of my RL agent for the Atari Breakout game decreasing after a certain number of episodes?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, pytorch

[image]

The agent is trying to master the [Atari Breakout game](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Breakout-v0/).

Here is my [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mXUkkq_CMm0CN_dUbjzuclAzVqjJxZIp)

Is that normal that `reward_100` decreased that much after it hits 4.5? Is there a way to avoid that behavior?

Be aware that `reward_100` is simply `mean_reward = np.mean(self.total_rewards[-100:])`. In other words, it is the mean over the last 100 rewards. On the graph, `reward_100` represents de y-axis and th number of episodes the x-axis.

Comment: These are just general questions about your ML approach. Are you decaying the learning rate? And how are you trading off exploitation and exploration?

Comment: Decaying the learning rate seems to be the right thing to do. It changed a lot of things.

Comment: Nice! Maybe you can provide a formal answer below, once you solve your problem ;)

Comment: What algorithm are you using?

Comment: @RayWalker I used just a standard DQN. Look at my code in the question to know more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good practice to include this information in the question. All the best to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that decaying the learning rate solved my problem. I changed `learning_rate` from `0.001` to `0.0001`

[image]

Comment: Hi jgauth, great that decreasing the learning rate has solved your issue. By "decaying the learning rate" @nbro most probably meant to decrease the learning rate **during training**. This means that instead of a fixed learning rate you use a function that takes the amount of passed training steps as input and outputs a learning rate.

Comment: @RayWalker Thanks, I did not notice that. It might be a good idea!